# Intuition behind using a hashmap or set in the question Check If N and Its Double Exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, set

*Given an array arr of integers, check if there exists two integers N and M such that N is the double of M ( i.e. N = 2 * M).*

More formally check if there exists two indices i and j such that :

- i != j
- 0 <= i j < arr.length
- arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]

I have solved this question using nested loops and T/C for the approach is obviously O(n^2). But I have seen the solutions using hashmap or set in Javascript which essentially brings the T/C to O(n). But, I am not getting the intuition behind using a set in this question. How is it relevant? If anyone could explain this, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your array to an object or set.
Loop through the array, check if element * 2 is in the object/set.

```js
const arr = [1,3,5,7,9,11,14];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(el => [el, true])); // O(n)
// obj looks like
//{ "1": true, "3": true, etc}

// loop through arr until we find an element such that twice the element is in obj.  Can use O(1) lookups in obj

const result = arr.some(el => obj[el * 2]); // O(n) (usually less)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That I understood and that's what I said that I have solved the question using both the approach the nested loop approach and using a set or a hashmap. My question is what is the intuition behind using a set to solve this question? How is the application of Set relevant or applicable here?

Comment: I guess for the O(1) lookups.  If I have a set or object with known keys, I don't have to search through it in O(n) time.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Now it's somewhat clear. Thank-you.